# C# classes on the name file

Tags: c#, .net, class

Just learning C# for the first time in the last few days, and I'm wondering, my tutorial says to make a class on a different cs file within the project's folder. I've seen its possible to have multiple classes on the same file, but what is best practice?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# .cs file name and class name need to be matched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2224653/c-sharp-cs-file-name-and-class-name-need-to-be-matched)

Comment: Hugely subjective. Do whatever works for you (including your own maintenance needs etc). It may depend on class size.

Comment: Ok, sorry for duplicate, thanks anyway.